# Play: Get information if Action is deprecated inside of itself

Tags: scala, reflection, playframework

I have a situation like this:

```
@Singleton
class FooController @Inject() () {
   @deprecated("Use bar instead", "22.10.2020")
   def getFoo(param: Int): Action[AnyContent] =
      userAction { ... }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
def userAction(f: (Request[AnyContent], UserInfo) => Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent] =
   simpleAction { ... }

def simpleAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent] =
   ...
```

The `simpleAction` takes care of things like logging, de- and serialization and some other metadata related stuff. It isn't only used by `userAction`, but I added this as an example that shows the layering of methods isn't flat.

What I need to find out in `simpleAction`, for purposes of logging, is if one of the callers (in this case `getFoo`) has been marked as `@deprecated`.

I think it's possible by parsing the stack trace, and then reflecting on the method to find all annotations. But this solution isn't perfect.

Comment: AFAIK there's no other way to know if a method is marked as deprecated.

Comment: I'd probably rather use a parameter in `simpleAction` than rely on the `@deprecated` annotation for your need though.

Comment: @GaëlJ That would work, yes, but `@deprecated` is already used as a standard across the code base I am working with, so it's easier to not have to adjust everything.
I am surprised Play doesn't offer an out-of-the-box solution for deprecating endpoints...
Anyways, see the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

We have meanwhile found a solution that works surprisingly well:

```scala
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

// Inside the action:

val handler = request.attrs(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef)

val isDeprecated = ru
      .runtimeMirror(getClass().getClassLoader())
      .staticClass(handler.controller)
      .asType
      .toType
      .decl(ru.TermName(handler.method))
      .annotations
      .exists(_.tree.tpe =:= ru.typeOf[deprecated])
```